# remote machine IIS management using commandline

Tags: iis

help me to manage IIS (what i am trying to do is create virtual directory, set properties 
of virtual directory) on a remote PC/Server.

and check iis is runnning, and a particular virtual directory exists.

iisvdir.vbs helps to manage iis on local system, how can i use it for managing remote systems.

or is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it my self, but if any one has better of doing this let me know.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816568

to list the virtual directories
The iisweb /query command uses the following syntax:
iisweb /query WebSite [WebSite...] [/s Computer [/u [Domain]User /p Password]]

to create the virtual directory.
The iisvdir /create command uses the following syntax:
iisvdir /create WebSite [/Virtual Path]Name Physical Path [/s Computer [/u [Domain] User /p Password]]

it has servername in it.

Comment: does this work on IIS7 or higher? I don't see these commands installed

Answer (score 3):

You could do a lot worse than powershell and the IIS provider:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/429/installing-the-iis-70-powershell-provider/

even without the provider, powershell with WMI is x10 easier than with vbs.